# How to upload 100mb or a big file with email in php

Tags: php

I am not able to attach a big file with email around 60mb,please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: what do you mean attach a big file with email, send a email with a big file attachment. or upload a big file to a website.

Comment: Attach a big file with email and send a email with a big file attachment.

Comment: It depends on your mail-server (smtp) and the mail-server (smtp) of the receiver ... so you have no options to set in php.ini like post_upload etc ... in pratic it is not normal to send such big emails there a other ways to parse big data like ftp, cloud, web (download) ...

Answer (score 0):

Mainly for security reasons, all email server providers limit the maximum email size that an email account can receive.

Otherwise, if there would be no maximum email size limit, the email server would risk to be bombarded with very large emails, causing it to cease working properly.

[Here](https://www.outlook-apps.com/maximum-email-size/) is a list for size limit for various clients and some workarounds.

You can upload the files-to-be-attached to cloud storage servers (like DropBox, Google Drive or SkyDrive) and include the download link in your email

Comment: I am sending attachment to server's mail account,do i have to update anything there,i have changed upload_max_size = 128M,post_max_size =128M, memory_limits=200M and execution time to 7200 in php ini,do i update anything else

Comment: that all about the gmail and outbox and all,i have to send mail on server's mail account

Comment: I dont think that is possible. BTW gmail and outlook are also mail servers.